# Has anyone tried to write an itunes alternative for linux?

Tags: music, ipod, itunes

It seems to me that it would not be to hard to parse the database schema on an iPod and make a working application on Linux that could load and manage songs.  There is no hope left in me that Apple will support Linux users in any way if we buy there products like my current iPod 5g running IOS 9.2, so it seems we must help ourselves here.

Yes booting over to my win10 partition is an option but I am very resistant to doing that because of the very long time to start and shut-down since so many updates seem to accumulate during the times I (rarely) boot over to that partition.  And honestly I don't like Windows that much after seeing how easy, customizable and fast my Linux is.

The suggested solutions like Amorok, Rythmbox, Banshee and every other Linux music app I have tried have been unsuccessful at connecting to any but the very oldest iPods running IOS 6 or less.  I may just have to switch to Android music players in the future as my last resort.  Any developers out there with ideas or experience trying to write software to communicate with the iPod?

Comment: NONE of those solutions answer my question.  I have tried all of them and they fail.  So I am still looking for a working answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) they have brought a lot of Apple device services to Linux. If you take a scroll down their page you will see the current status of all services. The one you are looking for is:

> Music/Video Synchronization   DBVersion <= 4  4.3.5
>
> Rhythmbox, gtkpod and
>   Amarok sync with latest libgpod >= 0.7.90. The iPhone 4/4S, iPod Touch
>   4, iPad 1/2/3rd Gen and Apple TV do NOT work.
>       Any device with DBVersion > 4 does NOT work. To check your DBVersion run "ideviceinfo -q com.apple.mobile.iTunes -k DBVersion".
>   WIP.

They don't go into too much detail why music sync is so far behind however there is this report on there page:

> 14.10.2011: iOS 5 music sync has a lot of changes. Linux users who want to sponsor the required implementations feel free to donate.

Maybe you can ask the guy's there if you can help.

Comment: Thanks man, I always thought it was  my bad, and it seems my ipod 5th gen can't be synched that way... that's a shame but now I can end my pointless quest